# ASP.NET Identity связь с таблицей AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Осваиваю новую систему авторизации ASP.NET Identity и возник следующий вопрос.
При использовании подхода code first все отлично формируется, но мне необходимо добавить далее таблицу Articles, которая должна содержать внешний ключ на таблицу AspNetUsers (необходимо вытянуть имя пользователя который добавил статью, таблица формируется средствами ASP.NET Identity), пытаюсь делать в классе Article что-то типа:

```
    public Guid AspNetUserId { get; set; }

    public AspNetUsers AspNetUser { get; set; }
```

Но AspNetUsers подсвечивает красным и таблицы не видит. Подскажите как получить связь такую.
И еще, не возникнет ли у меня проблема в получении ID пользователя для внесения его в таблицу Articles.
За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У себя реализовывал так:

```
//Этот класс уже должен быть в проекте
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    // Тут устанавливаем связь с нашей таблицей
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Articles = new List<Article>();
    }

}

//Модель данных "Статьи"
public class Article
{
    // ID статьи
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // название статьи
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // описание статьи
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //ASP.NET Identity использует тип string для ID пользователя
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}

//Контекст данных
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо:) сработало. Если Вам не сложно проясните пожалуйста несколько моментов:
1.метод GenerateUserIdentityAsync я так понимаю будет использоваться для получения информации о пользователе?и если да то что для этого надо?
2. для чего объявляли  public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles, у нас же получается что связь должна быть один-ко-многим, а объявление коллекции вроде как характерно для многие ко многим.
3. public static ApplicationDbContext Create() и вот это для чего?
извините заранее за глупые вопросы, только учусь. блин столко вопросов столько вопросов(