# Blazor Asp.net hosted identity. Отношения ApplicationUser к общим моделям

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2, blazor

Blazor Asp.net hosted и Identity.

Как создавать и работать с моделями которые по задумке должны иметь отношения с `ApplicationUser`, но при этом использоваться как на стороне клиента, так и сервера?

Я имею в виду, что Blazor Asp.net hosted разделен на три проекта: Client, Server, Shared. В папке Shared лежит модель `Portfolio` которая должна иметь отношение с `ApplicationUser` один к одному. Как в Blazor создавать такую связь?

Из похожих вопросов нашел [ASP.NET Identity связь с таблицей AspNetUsers](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/338387/asp-net-identity-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-aspnetusers?rq=1) но, там модель Article видимо находится на сервере, раз в ней можно создать:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Меня же интересует использование общего класса, чтобы не дублировать их на клиенте и сервере, лишь с той разницей отсутствия ссылки на ApplicationUser в классе клиента.

Comment: Я решил не использовать Identity и завилосипедил это всё, но по другим причинам.

Comment: Мне не очень ясна суть вашего вопроса, вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем